# Calling Tosca CI using following command from Jenkins Execute Windows batch command getting API not initialized error

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, tosca

I am initiating Tosca from a Jenkins pipeline by using the 'Execute Windows batch command' with the following script

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\TRICENTIS\Tosca Testsuite\ToscaCommander\ToscaCI\Client\ToscaCIClient.exe" -m local`

When running the pipeline, I encountered the following error.

```
*Started by user administrator
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\poc
[poc] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins1691088736952524856.bat
C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\poc>"C:\Program Files (x86)\TRICENTIS\Tosca Testsuite\ToscaCommander\ToscaCI\Client\ToscaCIClient.exe" -m local 
*********************************************************
* Tricentis                                             *
* www.tricentis.com                                     *
* support@tricentis.com                                 *
*********************************************************
* TOSCACI-Client 23.1.4.2607                            *
*********************************************************
 Client state:
---------------------------------------------------------
2023-11-08 12:54:18,948  -  Client started
---------------------------------------------------------
2023-11-08 12:54:18,984  - Starting local execution
2023-11-08 12:54:18,985  - Configuration File Path:
2023-11-08 12:54:18,990  - Getting license...
2023-11-08 12:55:15,530  - Opening workspace: C:\Tosca_Projects\Tosca_Workspaces\Tosca Demo\Tosca Demo.tws
2023-11-08 12:55:15,531  - is server login successful False
2023-11-08 12:55:30,721  - Executing CI Test...
2023-11-08 12:55:30,754  - API not initialized
Server stack trace: 
   at Tricentis.TCAPIObjects.TCConnectionBase.GetAttributeValueByName(TCObjectBase obj, String attributeName)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)
Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Tricentis.TCAPIObjects.TCConnectionBase.GetAttributeValueByName(TCObjectBase obj, String attributeName)
   at Tricentis.TCAPIObjects.Objects.TCObject.GetAttribute[T](String attributeName)
   at TOSCAContinuousIntegration.TOSCACIExecution.CITestExecutor.ExecuteCITest(String resultType, TCWorkspace workspace)
   at TOSCAContinuousIntegration.TOSCACIExecution.CITestExecutionController.ExecuteViaAPI(String resultType, AbstractCITestConfigurationRootNode testConfigurationRoot, AbstractCITestExecutor executor)
2023-11-08 12:55:30,755  - Closing workspace and restoring license...
2023-11-08 12:55:30,786  - Main: TCApiException occured
System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Object '/8d3b3bac_5d42_49e6_8a24_5ee2c8ec088d/yqvrb5uyq0masog2g5yd42+b_2.rem' has been disconnected or does not exist at the server.
Server stack trace: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.ChannelServices.CheckDisconnectedOrCreateWellKnownObject(IMessage msg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.ChannelServices.SyncDispatchMessage(IMessage msg)
Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Tricentis.TCAPIObjects.TCConnectionBase.get_MetaSettingsPath()
   at Tricentis.TCAPI.TCAPI.get_MetaSettingsPath()
   at Tricentis.TCAPI.TCAPI.get_MetaSettingsPath()
   at TOSCAContinuousIntegration.TOSCACIExecution.CILicenseHandler.get_MetaSettingsPath()
   at TOSCAContinuousIntegration.TOSCACIExecution.CILicenseHandler..ctor()
   at TOSCAContinuousIntegration.TOSCACIExecution.CILicenseHandler.get_LicenseHandler()
   at TOSCAContinuousIntegration.TOSCACIExecution.CIExecutionManager.ExecuteTest(String resultType)
   at TOSCAContinuousIntegration.TOSCACIClient.Dispatching.LocalDispatcher.Execute(Boolean considerResults)
   at TOSCAContinuousIntegration.TOSCACIClient.Dispatching.LocalDispatcher.Execute(Boolean considerResults)
   at TOSCAContinuousIntegration.TOSCACIClient.Program.Main(String[] args)
C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\poc>exit -1 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE*
```

Comment: did you find the fix this issue?